# How can i achieve the following in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm trying to convert below table to the desired output like below.
how can i achieve the below desired output table

Data Set:

```
question_id    element_id
1              7
1              8
1              z
2              x
2              9
2              10
3              10
3              11
3              12
3              y
```

Desired Result:

```
question_id    element_id       element
1              7                   z
1              8                   z
2              9                   x
2              10                  x
3              10                  y
3              11                  y
3              12                  y
```

OR

```
question_id    element_id       element
1              7                   z
1              8                   null
2              9                   x
2              10                  null
3              10                  y
3              11                  null
3              12                  null
```

Comment: I keep rolling back because your edits invalidate the 2 answers given below.  You should not change your question dramatically after several other users have already given answers.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I'm trying to achieve below result output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63904905/im-trying-to-achieve-below-result-output)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use conditional aggregation to find the non digit value for each `question_id` group, with the help of analytic functions:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT t.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY question_id
                                   ORDER BY element_id) rn
    FROM yourTable t
),
cte2 AS (
    SELECT
        question_id,
        element_id,
        CASE WHEN rn = 1
             THEN MAX(CASE WHEN REGEXP_LIKE(element_id, '^[A-Za-z]+$')
                           THEN element_id END)
                  OVER (PARTITION BY question_id) END AS element
    FROM cte
)

SELECT
    question_id,
    element_id,
    element
FROM cte2
WHERE
    REGEXP_LIKE(element_id, '^[0-9]+$')
ORDER BY
    question_id,
    element_id;
```

[image: screen capture from demo link below]

### Demo

Answer (score 1):

You seem to want the one non-numeric value on each row for each question and then to filter out so only numeric elements in the the results.  If so:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             max(case when regexp_like(element_id, '[^0-9]') then element_id end) over (partition by question_id) as element
      from t
     ) t
where regexp_like(element_id, '^[0-9]+$');
```