# I'm trying to achieve below result output

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

can we get the below desired table by using  PIVOT or something. I'm trying to convert below table to the desired output like below.

Data Set:

```
question_id    element_id
1              john
1              bran
1              o_siera
2              brook
2              joseph
2              o_daniel
2              o_cody
3              derick
3              james
3              sophia
3              o_sandra
3              o_ashley
```

Desired Result:

```
question_id    element_id       element
1              john             o_siera
1              bran             o_siera
2              brook            o_daniel
2              joseph           o_daniel
3              derick           o_sandra
3              james            o_sandra
3              sophia           o_sandra
```

OR

OR can we achieve it in this way

```
question_id    element_id       element
1              john             o_siera
1              bran             
2              brook            o_daniel,o_cody
2              joseph           
3              derick           o_sandra, o_ashley
3              james            
3              sophia
```

Comment: what exactly is the rule you are applying to convert the table?

Comment: I'm just posting my question here on how to achieve it. Not sure about the rule

Comment: Ok does it matter which element_id the string aggregation of 'o_%' elements is associated with?

Comment: Yes. It does matter

Comment: alphabetically?  It's good to include in the question :)

Comment: No it doesn't require any alphabetical order

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not an ideal data model.  Something like this should work except when a value that begins with 'o_%' is an element_id and not an element.

This was not tested.

```
select t1.question_id
    ,case when t1.element_id not like 'o_%' then t1.element_id else '' end element_id
    ,case when t2.element_id like 'o_%' then t2.element_id else '' end element
from table t1
    join table t2 on t1.question_id=t2.question_id
```

Comment: It is working fine but it is creating some extra rows.

Comment: Add a WHERE field NOT NULL to eliminate those.

Comment: Your query works excellent when the element_id's starting with o_ are at the last of each group. But what if we have element_id's starting with o_ in the middle of each group

Comment: Or can we write the case statement to search the whole group instead of stop searching when the condition is true

Comment: If possible, all of the ```'o_%'```  values should be stored in a separate column.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest:

```
select t.*, max_o
from (select t.*,
             max(case when element_id like 'o\_%' then element_id end) over (partition by question_id) as max_o
      from t
     ) t
where element_id not like 'o\_%';
```

Comment: What if we have element_id's even after o_%